# Has anyone lost money after using Freewallet app?

Tags: third-party-wallets

I'm wondering if anyone from this community used Freewallet org app? You can see that Freewallet is scam. They steal assets and block wallets for no reason!

Comment: In future, please review https://monero.stackexchange.com/help and particularly https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/promotion, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if anyone from this community used Freewallet org app?

Lots of users were caught out by this scam. See https://monero.stackexchange.com/search?q=freewallet and https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/search/?q=freewallet

Answer (score 0):

My experience began with a 250 deposit, but now they suddenly demand identity verification, despite no changes to my email or account information. Now they want me to jump through hoops like a circus clown. It's the worst wallet ever! There are so many wallets out there, but this one should be avoided at all costs. Let's all speak up and file complaints against Freewallet!